# Export Excel file to create html webpages

Tags: html, xml, excel, export

I'd like to know how you would try to solve the following problem:

I have an excel-spreadsheet containing "linked information" (like a matrix-type) of business processes which need to be transformed to HTML websites.
Only certain parts of the spreadsheet should be exported.
The needed data consists of a hierarchical representations of certain categories that hold different components.
So for example category 1 consists of component A which has sub-components A1, A2 and so on.

The goal is to represent that single excel spreadsheet with html websites where the main-categories lead to pages with subcategories (always listing which subcategories they hold) and so on. Kind of like a process or business flow-chart.
Whenever something gets changed, added, removed within the spreadsheet I'd like to reflect this new information with the webpages accordingly.

The important part would be not having to edit several webpages but have everything rebuild at once - with the right structure.

My first thoughts were to define one XSD file to extract and transform the data with XSL and there create the final web structure. I'm not quite sure how time-intensive this would be and if I could actually have a satisfying outcome.

Maybe you have a better solution for me or you can point me to some link where something similar is accomplished.

I hope I could get my problem across.

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE**

I made a simple version of my spreadsheet.

```
|*Sub*|*Description*|*Key*|
|SubName|some text| 11|
|SubName|some text| 11|
|SubName|some text| 21|
|SubName|some text| 22|
```

Here the "key"-column is needed to structure the final html layout where 11 and 12 belong to an even higher category 10 which later needs to be added to the result set. What also needs to be added is a "title-category" with the highest level of 1, 2 etc.

I want to reach a point where I can create an html webpage with the title categories being listed (just like headlines) and (on the same page) in some sort of rectangle frame one can see the next level of categories (here 10 and 20) which work as a link and take one to another webpage displaying category 10 and 20 now as headlines and have the sub-categories listed and clickable to reach the final, detailed table listing. So basically it's a top-to-bottom drill down of information.

I have three excel files with these title categories (for example: customers, orders, services)

Returning these three spreadsheets in one html webpage would be the goal. And from there one could click through to the detail pages. For now I'd be happy just to get one spreadsheet in order.

Has anyone got a good idea how I can:

- a) write a schema-file to receive a proper xml file,
- b) and of course turn the xml file to an html file.

if you can point me to some examples with a similar problem, I'd be happy as well.

thanks for your support.

Comment: Using XSL to transform the XML into HTML is an excellent choice, I'm not sure there is anything better out there. It should not be too much effort if you have a basic understanding of XSL, and there are tons of examples around.

Comment: As you said, `write a schema-file to receive a proper xml file`, since html is xml :)

Comment: would you be so kind and show me an example to my table example? I cannot add the 2 main categories needed, can I?